# Why is Georgina cleaning in "Get Out"?

Tags: get-out

I just saw Get Out, and there's one thing I don't understand.

Georgina turns out to be controlled by Rose's grandmother; its grandmothers brain in her body. Why then, is Georgina constantly cleaning and being treated like an actual maid.

During the diner scene, we get a glimpse into the kitchen, and we see Georgina holding up a plate in way that suggested that she was made to work and cook. The pose and the fact that she was already standing there holding the plate before Missy enters the kitchen was also quite strange and suggestive.

Also, at the "party" theres a moment that Chris sees Georgina and Missy. For a moment he thinks that Georgina is being involved in the party, but than it turns out the Georgina is just handed empty glasses to take care of.

So this I don't get. If its really grandma inside Georgina, then why is she treated in this way?

Comment: Any indication they treat her that way when they aren't trying to deceive another live body they want to snatch?

Answer (score 11):

Two reasons:

1. She has to at least appear to be a servant to deflect suspicion. What would Chris think if the maid were just sitting around?
2. Maybe Grandma was house-proud and liked keeping the kitchen clean. Having a youthful body might actually have prompted her to be more active, and keeping things clean would be one way of doing so.